# How to politely make massive amounts of api calls?

Tags: python

I have a script that takes about 15 minutes to run. It basically hits a bunch of api endpoints. Because some of our production services run on where these endpoints are hosted, I want to throttle my script (which runs weekly) so it won't impact our systems as much. What's the easiest way to do this? The script is mostly for loops. Should I just add some sleep statements or is there a more standardized way to do this? I don't care if the script takes a long time to run, because I'll run it overnight.

```
for i in list: <-big list 
   make_call_to_api() <-typically couple seconds
   time.sleep(5) <-sleep 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think using time is fine.** However alternatively you can use [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects):

```
from threading import Timer

def make_api_with_interval(*arg, **kwargs):
    # BODY of make api call
    make_call_to_api()
    Timer(30.0, make_api_with_interval, ["args"], {'kwarg': 'kwarg'}).start()

Timer(30.0, make_api_with_interval).start() # after 30 seconds, api call would be performed.
```